# Invalid security token when specifying other another region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am using an assumed role, all environment variables has been set (`AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`, `AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`)

When I call `aws sts get-caller-identity` on my default region (`ap-southeast-1`) it doesn't have a problem

```
$ awsudo -u somerolename aws sts get-caller-identity --region ap-southeast-1
{
    "UserId": "XXXXXYYYYYZZZZZZ:botocore-session-1234567",
    "Account": "111122223333",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::111122223333:assumed-role/somerolename/botocore-session-2222333344"
}
```

But when I change it to the region that I am trying to work on (`ap-southeast-3`), an error happens

```
$ awsudo -u somerolename aws sts get-caller-identity --region ap-southeast-3
An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetCallerIdentity operation: The security token included in the request is invalid
```

How do I resolve this?, I have tried other regions as well, but it seems only `ap-southeast-1` works

Answer (score 2):

I think you are facing this issue, because `ap-southeast-3` region is not enabled for your account. You can check if it is enabled by running the following command:

```
aws ec2 describe-regions --region-names ap-southeast-3
```

If your region is not enabled, you will get the following response:

```
{
    "Regions": [
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.ap-southeast-3.amazonaws.com",
            "RegionName": "ap-southeast-3",
            "OptInStatus": "not-opted-in"
        }
    ]
}
```

In order to enable it, you just have to follow the instructions from the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande-manage.html):

> To enable a Region
>
> - Sign in to the AWS Management Console.
> - In the upper right corner of the console, choose your account name or number and then choose My Account.
> - In the AWS Regions section, next to the name of the Region that you want to enable, choose Enable.
> - In the dialog box, review the informational text and choose Enable Region.
> - Wait until the Region is ready to use.

Please note, enabling a region may take some time. As far as I've experienced, this time is fairly short. You should get an email as soon as the region is enabled.

Comment: I have already had it enabled previously, but I already solved the problem, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so apparently I had to make Global endpoints to be valid in all regions for STS

More on that is discussed [in this docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_enable-regions.html) in the **"Managing global endpoint session tokens"** section